Pre-commit hooks in R/RStudio. How do I change the max line length to 120?
From the precommit package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/precommit/index.html), I'm taking the default pre-commit-config.yml file as my starting point. You can recreate it with precommit::use_precommit() but I've given a simplified version below.
My commits are failing because of line lengths of over 80. I'd like to increase this to 120. I've tried and tried, but can't get this to work.
What's not working is adding args to lintr, for example...
 args: 
      --linters_with_defaults
      - object_name_linter
      - "line_length_linter(120)"

...doesn't make a difference.
Is it just the case that tidyverse_style absolutely relies on 80 characters?
To recreate this, you could make a test.R file with the following:
# this line is realllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllly long


and a pre-commit-config.yml file with this simplified version. Then try and commit. Really greatful for any ideas at all at this point!
# All available hooks: https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html
# R specific hooks: https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/precommit
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/precommit
    rev: v0.4.3
    hooks: 
    -   id: style-files
        args: [--style_pkg=styler, --style_fun=tidyverse_style]    
    -   id: lintr
        args: 
          - --linters_with_defaults
          - object_name_linter
          - "line_length_linter(120)"
    -   id: readme-rmd-rendered
    -   id: parsable-R
    -   id: no-browser-statement
    -   id: no-debug-statement
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v1.2.3
    hooks: 
    -   id: check-added-large-files
        args: ['--maxkb=200']
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
        exclude: '\.Rd'
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: forbid-to-commit
        name: Don't commit common R artifacts
        entry: Cannot commit .Rhistory, .RData, .Rds or .rds.
        language: fail
        files: '\.(Rhistory|RData|Rds|rds)$'
        # `exclude: <regex>` to allow committing specific files

With this set-up, when I do a git commit, this is the failure message I get:
git commit -m "test"
style-files..............................................................Passed
lintr....................................................................Failed
- hook id: lintr
- exit code: 1

File `test.R` is not lint free
C:\Users\justin.beresford\repos\template_r\test.R:1:81: style: [line_length_linter] Lines should not be more than 80 characters. This line is 88 characters.
# this line is realllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllly long


can you show the command you ran and the output?

Thanks, good point, I've added the command and output to the bottom of the question :)
